# EMR Spark Fails to Write Small PySpark Dataframe to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I am trying to write a dataframe to S3.  My main goal is writing millions of rows, but I am starting out small and to no avail - a 10-row dataframe wrote succesffully to S3, but 100 rows doesn't write, the job aborts because SparkContext was shut down.  Moreover, since the first job aborted, running the cells that process the data before writing it is erratic and they don't always run successfully.

The EMR version is 5.32.0.  I tried 5.29.0 after reading this solved a similar problem, but this didn't help (sorry, can't find the post).

I am attaching the logs here in case someone can make sense of them.

Thanks in advance!!

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark as ps

df = spark.read.parquet(s3_path)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

raw_df = query.str("SELECT * FROM df") #This select queries a table with four joins which completed successfully in the past

from pyspark.sql.functions import datediff, current_date
raw_df = raw_df.withColumn('diam_',raw_df['diam'].cast("float").alias('diam'))
raw_df = raw_df.drop('diam')
raw_df = raw_df.withColumnRenamed('diam_', 'diam')
raw_df = raw_df.withColumn('diam2', pow(raw_df['diam'], 2))

raw_df = raw_df.withColumn('indate_', raw_df['indate'].cast('date'))
raw_df = raw_df.withColumn('conint_', raw_df['conint'].cast('date'))
raw_df = raw_df.drop('indate').withColumnRenamed('indate_', 'indate')
raw_df = raw_df.drop('conint').withColumnRenamed('conint_', 'conint')
raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("current_date", current_date())
raw_df = raw_df.withColumn("r_age", 
                           datediff(raw_df['current_date'], raw_df['indate'])/365)
raw_df = raw_df.withColumn('r_age_', raw_df['r_age']/365)
raw_df = raw_df.drop('current_date')
raw_df = raw_df.drop('r_age')
raw_df = raw_df.withColumnRenamed('r_age_','r_age')
raw_df.count()

raw_df.write.parquet("s3://PATH/training_data_100")
```

The code fails with the following traceback:

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o138.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 35 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:972)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:970)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:970)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:2286)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$6.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1949)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1948)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend$MonitorThread.run(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
    ... 33 more

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 843, in parquet
    self._jwrite.parquet(path)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o138.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 35 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:972)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:970)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:970)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:2286)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2193)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$6.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1949)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1948)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend$MonitorThread.run(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Are you able to see the count?

Comment: I am able to see the count.  But, it's sporadic (on completely different clusters) - sometimes the code is so slow, after having read the files into dataframes that the count fails with a similar error involving SparkContext shut down or session dead